# Html.HiddenFor helper throwing null exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass a value from the model...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null or empty.

But it is throwing this exception and I don't know why... And no ProductId isn't null.

Action

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int ProductId = 0)
    {
        PCsViewModel pcViewModel = new PCsViewModel();
        ProductRepository productRepo = new ProductRepository();
        Product dbProduct = productRepo.GetAll(item=>item.ID==ProductId);
        PCsRepository pcsRepo = new PCsRepository();
        PC dbPC = pcsRepo.GetAll(item=>item.ProductID==ProductId);
        if (dbProduct != null && dbPC != null)
        {
            pcViewModel = new PCsViewModel(dbProduct,dbPC);
        }
        return View(pcViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PCsInfo { get; set; }//for the front view
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Processor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string OS { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RAM { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Storage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string VideoCard { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public PCsViewModel()
        {

        }

        public PCsViewModel(Product product, PC pc)
        {
            this.ProductId = product.ID;
            this.CategoryID = product.CategoryID;
            this.OS = product.OS;
            this.Processor = product.Processor;
            this.Name = product.Name;
            this.RAM = product.RAM;
            this.Storage = product.Storage;
            this.VideoCard = pc.VideoCard;
            this.PCsInfo = "PC "+product.Name + "with processor " + product.Processor;
            this.Price = (double)product.Price;
            this.ImagePath = Path.Combine(Constants.ImagesPCsDirectory, product.ImageName);
        }
```

Comment: You may want to consider posting what your Controller Action and Model that are being used here look like. It might help clear up exactly what the issue could be.

Comment: @RionWilliams just posted it

Comment: I don't see anything that immediately stands out using your code. Since you are always passing a model to your View (either populated or not), it shouldn't throw this exception [as seen here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0vGUO). Are you sure that the model being bound to this view is a `PCsViewModel` (i.e. the top of your View should have `@model YourProject.ViewModels.PCsViewModel`)?

Comment: @model PCsViewModel

Comment: @RionWilliams it's there but .... And the value is 0 by default... why is it saying it is null

Comment: That's strange. Does it change if you use the property directly instead of the lambda expression (e.g. `@Html.Hidden("ProductId", Model.ProductId")`)? Is it just this specific property that is causing the issue (i.e. if you remove this one, does the View render as expected)? This is on the actual initial rendering of the View and not after a `POST` occurs right?

Comment: @RionWilliams still getting the same exception when I changed to Html.Hidden, yea it's on the initial rendering

Comment: Does it break with just that specific property? You might try posting the entire View as something isn't right here.

Comment: @RionWilliams oh.. when I even removed the Html.hidden I am still getting the exception.. right on the opening curly brace "@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "PCs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

Comment: @RionWilliams {"Value cannot be null or empty.\r\nParameter name: contentPath"} still the same error...

Comment: Do you have any uses of the `Url.Content()` helper? If so, you may want to check and ensure that you aren't passing null to it (or any "empty" values), which might be the case if you are passing in a value from your model.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would assume _if_ you had that you were probably passing your `Model.ImagePath` property to it, which would blow up if empty / null. If that is the case, you will want to add the necessary null checking to _only_ attempt to render that section if a path was available.

Comment: @RionWilliams yea that was the problem... how to fix it haha

Comment: @RionWilliams good guess... you deserve a vote up

Comment: I've added an answer which should explain how to go about fixing it, based off what I know about your structure / view at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of the discussion in the comments, it looks like your actual issue wasn't related to the `ProductId` property but instead your `ImagePath` property, which was being passed into a `Url.Content()` helper (to resolve the appropriate path).

This would work as expected if the path existed, but if that property was null or empty, you would receive the `ArgumentNullException` that you currently are. The best approach would likely be to just only render the specific path *if* that specific property wasn't null:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImagePath)) {
    // Use Url.Content(Model.ImagePath) within here safely
}
```

There are multiple different ways to handle this, such as adding an additional property on your model to clean things up:

```
public bool HasImage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagePath);
```

And then use:

```
@if (Model.HasImage) {
    // Use Url.Content(Model.ImagePath) within here safely
}
```

Comment: strange thing with MVCs is that sometimes the exception occurs in later code but the arrow points to some code before that and you wonder what is happening... any idea why is that?